# What do the TreatAsSymbol attributes do?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to make a Notepad++ Syntax Highlighter --> Ace Editor Syntax Highlighter converter. It seems pretty simple to do and hopefully will help others out also.

I've been looking at the syntax highlighter xml file at the moment.

What do the attributes of `NodepadPlus.UserLang.Settings.TreatAsSymbol` do...?

I.E.  What do these do?:

`NodepadPlus.UserLang.Settings.TreatAsSymbol.comment="no"` `NodepadPlus.UserLang.Settings.TreatAsSymbol.commentLine="yes"`

Comment: Really not sure how the question was too broad, but I've made some edits...

Comment: Does that editor have no documentation at all? Or even a forum to ask on?

Comment: @Rob: It does have documentation, but [it doesn't provide a meaningful description of this option at all](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Editing_Configuration_Files#User_defined_languages:_userDefineLang.xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TreatAsSymbol was an option from UDL older than 2.0 that, when unchecked (i.e. set to "no" in the XML), made it so whitespace was required after the opening comment delimiters in order for them to be recognized as comment delimiters.

For example, with `TreatAsSymbol.commentLine="no"`, the following would be highlighted as a comment:

```
// Comment
```

but not the following:

```
//Comment
```

With TreatAsSymbol enabled, both lines would be highlighted as comments.

As of UDL 2.0 (included in Notepad++ 6.2, released in October 2012), TreatAsSymbol no longer has any effect. All user-defined languages support highlighting line comments and block comments without requiring whitespace after the opening delimiters. In fact, if you create a new UDL in a recent version of Notepad++ and export it, you'll notice that the `<TreatAsSymbol>` element is missing from the resulting XML altogether.

If you want to ensure backward compatibility with older versions of Notepad++, you'll still need to include this option manually in your UDL.